# Significance bars on coupled box plots

Tags: r, boxplot, significance

I have trying to put significance bars on my group boxplots but I cannot find a way. What I have for the moment is the following:

```
A <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,15,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,19,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,22,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,23,24,24,24,24,24,24,24,24)

B <- c(104.125,120.125,158.125,149.750,146.750,137.125,146.500,150.125,153.375,163.000,144.125,163.625,167.875,163.250,167.500,180.000,153.500,127.250,147.000,120.125,122.750,108.000,111.000,,64.250)

C <- c(84.625,113.625,120.875,133.750,134.125,139.875,129.625,127.125,137.125,128.375,143.250,146.125,156.000,140.625,154.875,160.125,174.000,185.000,174.750,183.125,167.000,153.875,132.750,102.375)

distrib_df <- data.frame(animal=c(rep(“a1”,192),rep(“a2”,192)),
                           bins=as.factor(A),
                           each_vids=c(B,C)) 
max_y <- quantile(distrib_df[[3]],c(0.99))[[1]]
plot_distrib <- ggplot(data=distrib_df,aes(x=bins,
                                             y=each_vids,
                                             fill=animal)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_point(position=position_jitterdodge(),col=c(rep("red",(length(list_bins_)-correction)*8),rep("blue",(length(list_bins_)-correction)*8))) +
  labs(x="Time bins",
       y=label_y) +
  ylim(0,max_y+0.2*max_y).
```

Which gives me the output you can see below

[image]

I now want to put significance bar over each pair of boxplot. I have tried the following

```
plot_distrib  +
  geom_signif(stat="identity",
              data=data.frame(x=c(0.875,1.875),
                              xend=c(1.125,2.125),
                              y=rep(max_y,2),
                              annotation=c("MY","ASS")),
              aes(x=x,
                 xend=xend,
                 y=y,
                 yend=y,
                 annotation=annotation))
```

But this gives me the error message that I do not know how to solve.

[image]

Thanks by advance for your help!